# How to conditionally merge a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
Array
(    
    [10] => Array
    (
        [from] => Jack
        [to] => Terry
        [Bribe] => 0
        [Joke_Payment] => 0
        [Corrupt_Support] => 1
        [Legitimate_Support] => 0
        [Obfuscation] => 1
        [Legal_Enforcement] => 0
        [Whistleblower] => 0
    )

    [11] => Array
    (
        [from] => Terry
        [to] => Jack
        [Bribe] => 0
        [Joke_Payment] => 0
        [Corrupt_Support] => 1
        [Legitimate_Support] => 0
        [Obfuscation] => 0
        [Legal_Enforcement] => 1
        [Whistleblower] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to update the above array to like this: have a 1 (going `from` from `to` to) and a -1 for the opposite direction, a 2 signify for "both directions.

```
 Array (    [10] => Array
         (
             [from] => Jack
             [to] => Terry
             [Bribe] => 0
             [Joke_Payment] => 0
             [Corrupt_Support] => 2
             [Legitimate_Support] => 0
             [Obfuscation] => 1
             [Legal_Enforcement] => -1
             [Whistleblower] => 0
         ) }
```

How can I firstly calculate their intersect and then update the original array?

They will have the same amount to keys, and when `from` matches `to`, and `to` matches `from` element, I want to combine these two arrays into one. A '1' is used to indicate that the property relates in the `from` to `to` direction, and a `-1` indicates that the property goes in the reverse direction (from `to` to `from`).

My current code is:

```
$fileRelation = explode("\r", $end);
$rowsRelation = array_map('str_getcsv', $fileRelation);
$headerRelation = array_shift($rowsRelation);
$csvArrRelation = array();
$countR = count($headerRelation);
foreach ($rowsRelation as $key => &$row) {
    $index = 2;$sum = 0;$sumArr = array();
    while ($index < $countR) {
        if ($row[$index]>0) {
            $sumArr[$sum]=$index; //store row $headerRelation index
            $sum++;
        }
        $index++;
    }
    if($sum > 0){ //remove element if no relationship exist
        foreach ($csvArrRelation as $k => $a) {
            if (in_array($row[0], $csvArrRelation[$k]) && in_array($row[1], $csvArrRelation[$k])){
                $p = array_values($a);$i = 2;$cp= count($p);
                while($i < $cp ){
                if($row[$i] == $p[$i]){
                    $a[$headerRelation[$i]] += $row[$i];
                }else{
                    $a[$headerRelation[$i]] -= $row[$i];
                }
                $i++;
            }
                unset( $rowsRelation[$key] );
            }
        }
        $csvArrRelation[] = array_combine($headerRelation, $row);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could update your questions with some real data i.e. for $countR and $csvArrRelation, just simple examples. It would be easier for somebody to help you if he would know data structure. What do you mean actually by "intersect" ? I can't find connection between those two arrays and your desired result, so if you can, explain it little better. Note that there is an array_intersect function which computes the intersection of arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Are the arrays guaranteed to always have the same and same amount of keys? Why does it start at `10`? It feels like PHP is the wrong place to do this.

Comment: yes, they will have the same amount to keys, and when from matches to, and to matches from element, I want to merge the rest elements.  I exact this part as an example, that's why it starts at 10

Comment: @liuqian: "I've extracted this part as an example, that's why it starts at 10" - so there can be more than one transaction between people in the array?

Comment: @DanMan there are about 100 arrays in this array, but their will be only one or no match at all.

Comment: @liuqian: Why is the `Legal_Enforcement` result `-1`? Typo?

Comment: @DanMan, no, it means Legal_Enforcement is from Terry to Jack

Comment: It would be worth updating the question to indicate what `1` and `-1` actually mean - I had the same question as @DanMan.

Comment: I wonder if the code is rather complex for what you are trying to do (I've only scanned it quickly, mind you). It seems all you want are two nested `foreach()` loops to scan for inverse relationships. When you find the `Jack->Terry` record, you want to scan all other records to see if there is a `Terry->Jack` record. If there is, do your custom merge, add that as a new record, and delete the two originals.

Comment: @halfer thanks, I have fixed that part and updated the code above.

Comment: @Hassan: I think that feedback has already broadly been made. However, if there is something you think particularly needs clarification, then please say what it is.

Comment: @liuqian: I have added the clarification I requested. However, if you can have a `1` (going from `from` to `to`) and a `-1` for the opposite direction, what does a `2` signify? Is that a code for "both directions"?

Comment: @halfer Exactly! 2 means both directions...I guess I didn't make my point clear, not good at explain myself :P

Comment: How are you getting on with this, @liuqian?

Comment: @halfer, thanks, it's all good now.. haven't been logged in for a while, working on another issue, pls help if you have time;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write this for you, but here is a good start:

```
$newRelations = [];
$deletions = [];
foreach ($rowsRelation as $key1 => $row1)
{
    foreach ($rowsRelation as $key2 => $row2)
    {
        // Don't compare with self
        if ($key1 != $key2)
        {
            // Have we found a reverse match?
            if (
                $row1['from'] == $row2['to'] &&
                $row1['to'] == $row2['from']
            )
            {
                $newRelations[] = myMerge($row1, $row2);
                $deletions[] = $key1;
                $deletions[] = $key2;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Delete old rows
foreach ($deletions as $deleteKey)
{
    unset($rowsRelation[$deleteKey]);
}

//  Add in new rows
$rowsRelation = array_merge($rowsRelation, $newRelations);

function myMerge(array $row1, array $row2)
{
    // todo
}
```

My strategy is to compare each row with every other, and if a reverse match is found, we know a merge is due. To avoid corrupting the `foreach` loops, I add the new array value to a different array, and log which keys I wish to delete from the original. These are then merged/deleted after the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is some kind of game, so let's call "player 1" the player whose name appears in "from" field and "player 2" the one whose name appears in "to" field.

According to what I understood, you consider player 1's values positive and player 2's negative. Then you sum both values in "from player 1 to player 2" record and discard "from player 2 to player 1" record.

According to that rule, `Corrupt_Support` should end up with a value of 0, not 2.
Basically, after merging your records, you will not be able to tell the difference between no actions at all and actions that have cancelled each other.

Besides, there is no rule to chose a "winner", i.e. which "from" player will be retained, leading to potentially impractical results.
If you have 3 players Abe, Bob and Cal, you can end up with any possible order, for instance
`["Abe vs Bob", "Bob vs Cal" and "Cal vs Abe"]` or
`["Abe vs Bob", "Abe vs Cal" and "Cal vs Bob"]`.
Looking up actions for Bob will be rather problematic in the latter case.

Now if you still want to do that, here is a way that takes advantage of PHP hash tables to speed up the merge and choses the "winner" according to alphabetic order:

```
// use "from player 1 to player 2" relation as key
foreach ($relations as $r) $relation_pairs[$r['from'].'+'.$r['to']] = $r; 

// pick the "winners" according to alphabetic order
ksort ($relation_pairs);

// merge relations
while (list($k,$r) = each($relation_pairs)) // this will take elements deletion into account immediately, contrary to foreach
{
    $symetric = $r['to'].'+'.$r['from'];
    if (isset($relation_pairs[$symetric])) // found a symetric relation
    {
        foreach ($relation_pairs[$symetric] as $field=>$value) // combine all numeric fields
            if (is_numeric ($value)) 
                $relation_pairs[$k][$field] -= $value;
        unset ($relation_pairs[$symetric]); // get rid of symetric relation
    }
}
$compressed_relations = array_values ($relation_pairs); // get rid of keys
```